# Chrome Remote Desktop Curtain Mode is "curtaining" my remote session

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, windows-11

**Host OS:** Windows 11 Pro

I've installed Google Chrome Remote Desktop on both the host and client computers, and it connects with no problems when `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RemoteAccessHostRequireCurtain` is set to `0`.

I've completed all of the steps to [set up curtain mode described here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2799701?hl=en), using the command in `cmd` in Administrator mode so I didn't miss anything. The optional Windows 10 setup step is also completed as described.

When I change the "curtain" registry key on the host machine (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RemoteAccessHostRequireCurtain` set to `1`), then remote into the host machine, I'm connected but only see a blurry version of my background wallpaper.  I assume this is the "curtain" version of the computer.

It seems like Curtain Mode is working, but it's obfuscating the host machine's monitor *to the client*. Anyone have experience with this?

[image: This is what my remote session looks like from the client Machine.]
This is what the remote session looks like from the client machine.

Comment: I originally wanted curtain mode to prevent others from seeing my screen while remoted in AND to keep the monitor on to engage the GPU so I could get better framerates. I eventually gave up on curtain mode, turned off the monitor, and installed an HTMI dummy plug in order to get the FPS boost.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. To fix it, I had to go into **Windows Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options** and **turn off "Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts"**

Comment: This worked for me (though the option is called something different on my machine (windows 11 pro). Thank you! I thought I was going mad.

Answer (score 0):

Name of option little changed. **Windows Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options** and **turn off "For improved security, only allow Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts on this device (Recommended)"**

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the other answer by @3EF5 ?